# Custom `GroupStorageProvider` in Keycloak is recognized but not registered

Tags: keycloak

I have created a custom `GroupStorageProviderFactory` and an accompanying `GroupStorageProvider` for Keycloak's Docker image (`quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0`) version `18.0.0` as below:

```java
public class XylemGroupStorageProviderFactory
  implements GroupStorageProviderFactory<XylemGroupStorageProvider> {
    static String ID = "xylem-group-storage-provider";
    protected static final List<ProviderConfigProperty> CONFIG_PROPERTIES;
    static {
        CONFIG_PROPERTIES = ProviderConfigurationBuilder.create()
                .property().name("enabled")
                .type(ProviderConfigProperty.BOOLEAN_TYPE)
                .defaultValue("true")
                .add()
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return ID;
    }

    @Override
    public XylemGroupStorageProvider create(KeycloakSession session, ComponentModel model) {
        GroupStorageProviderModel groupModel = new GroupStorageProviderModel(model);
        groupModel.setEnabled(true);
        return new XylemGroupStorageProvider(session, groupModel);
    }


    @Override
    public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
        return CONFIG_PROPERTIES;
    }
}
```

I even went overboard to set `enabled` properties for it, but it should not have been necessary as I have a few other custom providers which are all enabled and work by default. This particular provider does show up on the Keycloak's `providers` page on the admin panel:

[image]

However, the factory's `create` method never gets invoked. And my custom group storage provider never comes into play. How can I enable this custom provider?

**Update:**

I also updated my Dockerfile's `entrypoint` to enable and use the extension. But I'm not sure I am feeding the correct information to the `kc.sh build` command.

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0 as builder

ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_FEATURES=authorization,recovery-codes,declarative-user-profile

COPY ./connective-keycloak-password-entropy-18.0.0.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/connective-keycloak-password-entropy-18.0.0.jar
COPY ./argon2-password-hash-provider-2.0.1.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/argon2-password-hash-provider-2.0.1.jar

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.0
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build --db postgres --features-disabled=impersonation --health-enabled=true --spi-group-storage-xylem-group-storage-provider-enabled=true --spi-group-storage=xylem-group-storage-provider && /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.declarative_user_profile=enabled -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.logging=debug --proxy edge"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the *GroupStorageProviderFactory* is located in the package *keycloak-server-spi-private* and not in *keycloak-server-spi*. The difference between these two packages is that:

1. The *keycloak-server-spi* package contains the public interfaces and classes for Keycloak server extensions.
   These are the interfaces and classes that can be implemented or extended by third-party developers to customize or extend Keycloak's functionality.
2. The *keycloak-server-spi-private* package contains private interfaces and classes that are used internally by Keycloak.
   These are not intended for external use and may change or be removed without notice in future releases.

In general, you should only use the public interfaces and classes in *keycloak-server-spi* for your extensions. You should not rely on any classes or interfaces in *keycloak-server-spi-private*, as they may not be available or may change in future releases.